# Android Studio kts gradle shows unresolved referece inside android block

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've tried the latest Giraffe and Hedgehog and both are showing the following error on every line inside the `android {}` block `Unresolved reference: namespace, buildType etc...`

I'm attaching a screenshot but I've took out the id just for this purpose.[image]

The whole code is this:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
    alias(libs.plugins.kapt)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.services)
}

android {
    namespace = ""
    compileSdk = 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = ""
    minSdk = 28
    targetSdk = 33
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation(project(":design"))
implementation(project(":features:onboarding"))

implementation(libs.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
implementation(libs.activity.compose)
implementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
implementation(libs.compose.material3)
implementation(libs.compose.ui)
implementation(libs.compose.animation)
implementation(libs.compose.foundation)
implementation(libs.compose.runtime)
implementation(libs.navigation)
implementation(libs.activity)
implementation(libs.fragment)

implementation(libs.hilt)
implementation(libs.hilt.navigation)
kapt(libs.hilt.kapt)

testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

I've tried to update to the latest gradle version which solved the alias bug with the version catalog, but I'm missing something. I have most of the things up to date and I cannot figure out where is the problem or how to solve it.